# Adding/removing many commands to the context menu is extremely slow, especially on large worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, contextmenu

Recently I noticed my context menu creation (which adds lots of macro buttons depending on the spreadsheet) is quite slow.

For testing purposes I have the below macro in the workbook object's VBA:

```
Private Sub App_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim OnActionString As String
    Dim cmdNew As CommandBarButton

    For Each icbc In Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls
        If icbc.Tag = "brccm" Then icbc.Delete
    Next icbc

    For i = 1 To 70
        Set cmdNew = Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls.Add
        With cmdNew
            .Caption = "RecordedOrNot"
            .OnAction = "UTILITY_RecordedOrNot"
            .BeginGroup = False
            .Tag = "brccm"
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Even on a blank worksheet, the right click context menu take about two seconds to appear. I have a large worksheet with about 80,000 rows and it takes seven seconds to appear.

Why is it slow? Is there a a way to speed it up? Is there a way of disabling something in Application.* while doing this that helps?

Comment: 70 items on a context menu? That sounds like a awful UX!  You might want to rethink the design.

Comment: That said,  do really need to remove and re-add them every time you right click? You could do a dif on the current state of menu and remove/add only the required changes

Comment: Or set it up once.  Possibly calling a marshalling Sub to handle any context requirements

Comment: The 70 is just an example to show how much such code slows things down.  Different columns, workbooks and worksheets change what appears in it so rather than keep track of all the combinations of those things I make the menu each time.  That is the use case I've seen described for this feature of Excel.  I'm mainly concerned about why this code is slow and in particular slower on large worksheets.

Comment: In general reads from excel objects are faster than writes.  So in this case I'd try checking if an item is in the menu first , then only add/delete if needed.  As to being slower on large sheets, i can't add anything to that, other trying disabling the usual app object properties

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to pre-load all the controls when the workbook is opened ... and then make the controls visible (or not) depending on your display logic. My testing on a sheet with random data in Range("A1:Z80000") indicated that this executes in about a third of the time vs adding and removing controls real-time (about 1.4s to show/hide vs 4.5s to remove/add on my PC).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim cmdNew As CommandBarButton
    Dim icbc As CommandBarControl
    Dim i As Long

    For Each icbc In Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls
        If icbc.Tag = "brccm" Then icbc.Delete
    Next icbc

    For i = 1 To 70
        Set cmdNew = Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls.Add
        With cmdNew
            .Caption = "RecordedOrNot"
            .OnAction = "UTILITY_RecordedOrNot"
            .BeginGroup = False
            .Tag = "brccm"
        End With
      Next

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim icbc As CommandBarControl

    For Each icbc In Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls
        If icbc.Tag = "brccm" Then
            icbc.Visible = False ' Include visibility logic here True/False
        End If
    Next icbc

End Sub
```